# Connection reset by peer by NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Hello I have a php dashboard of stream streams that uses php-fpm + NGINX however when using the ondmand function the NGINX returns me the following error described below.

2019/02/19 14:51:19 [error] 1214#0: *438 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 186.208.107.243, server: , request: "GET /live/thythy20/60628227/166.ts HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "goldpremium.ddns.net:8080"

Those who can help me are very grateful!